# Parsing X server authorization file

Tags: xorg, c, xcb

Is there any API's or documentation to facilitate in parsing the authorization file for X server?

I am using `xcb` to connect to a display. It accepts a `xcb_auth_info_t` struct for authorization info. However, I cannot find any information on how to build this structure. There doesn't seem to be any documentation on the format of the X server authorization files.

**Solution I settled with:**

It turns out, for `MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1` type X authority files, the `Xauth` structure (from `X11/Xauth.h`) members map directly to the `xcb_auth_info_t` members. So, just read an `Xauth` structure from your X authority file using `XauReadAuth`. Then copy over the `name`, `name_length`, `data`, and `data_length` members.

If you want a more portable way to parse the X authority file, you can refer to `xcb`'s source code. It is pretty messy, but it shouldn't be too difficult to adapt their source code for your own purposes. Refer to `xcb_util.c` for details on how to open a socket to a display. Once you have the socket, you can use methods from `xcb_auth.c` to create the `xcb_auth_info_t` struct (see the methods `_xcb_get_auth_info`, `get_auth_ptr`, and `compute_auth`).

I only needed to connect through unix sockets (`AF_UNIX`), so the code I ported over was fairly minimal. I mostly just used the `compute_auth` method (and its dependencies).

Comment: Here's the first page I found after googling "xcb_auth_info_t": http://xcb.freedesktop.org/manual/structxcb__auth__info__t.html

Comment: Thanks goldilocks. I'm trying to find information on the X server authorization file. When you start X, one option is `-auth authorization_file`, but I can't find much info on how that file is formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searches, it is like you doesn't have to build this structure yourself. Looks at this discussion:

[What's the right way to call xcb_connect_to_display_with_auth_info() given a Xauthority file](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=xorg-devel@lists.x.org&q=subject:%22What's%20the%20right%20way%20to%20call%20xcb_connect_to_display_with_auth_info()%20given%20a%20Xauthority%20file%3F%22&o=newest&f=1)

The Xauthory file is specified in the XAUTHORITY environement variable. This file is generated by the program that start the X server (xdm, startx or xauth itself for example according to the doc in *man xauth*)

A classical connection with auth file specified via the XAUTHORITY variable works like this :

- xcb_connect call xcb_connect_with_auth_info() with a auth info set as NULL
- xcb_connect_with_auth_info() call _xcb_get_auth_info() in order to get auth information from the default xauthority file.

If you really want to see how this function get the auth info:

```
git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/xcb/libxcb
```

- Look at the file **./libxcb/src/xcb_util.c** lines 478 to end
- Look at the file **./libxcb/src/xcb_auth.c** lines 312 to 379 for _xcb_get_auth_info()

Comment: Thanks a lot cedlemo. I need to get the authorization info from an arbitrary file, rather than the default Xauthority file. Nevertheless, the links you provided were extremely helpful and led me to a solution. I've updated the question with what I settled on.

Answer (score 3):

The authorization protocols and files are discussed briefly in the `xauth` and `Xsecurity` manual pages, and in more detail in those for the `Xau` library functions (`XauWriteAuth` etc.). The `xcb_auth_info_t` structure appears to be defined in the `/usr/include/xcb/xcb.h` file as follows:

```
/**
 * @brief Container for authorization information.
 *
 * A container for authorization information to be sent to the X server.
 */
typedef struct xcb_auth_info_t {
    int   namelen;  /**< Length of the string name (as returned by strlen). */
    char *name;     /**< String containing the authentication protocol name, such as "MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1" or "XDM-AUTHORIZATION-1". */
    int   datalen;  /**< Length of the data member. */
    char *data;   /**< Data interpreted in a protocol-specific manner. */
} xcb_auth_info_t;
```